# Filtering dropdown box to untick current month, then tick following months

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Good day all. I'm fairly new to VBA and I have certain questions at hand.
I'm currently automating a report in my line of work, and most of it has to do with filtering data to show current month, next month onward, and the next 2 months onward.

My questions are:

1. How do you filter a drop down box for it to un-tick the previous months, tick the next month (with respect to the current month), and to tick the following months ahead (without having to hard code that it would have to end at a certain month. Just coding it to available months ahead)? For example, my data is for November 2017. I would have to un-tick the previous months, including November, then tick December 2017 and the following months ahead

   **From recorded macro:**

November as current month (manually filtered)

```
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AY$18103").AutoFilter Field:=37, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "10/18/2018", 1, "12/28/2017")
```

The current month code that I use in a different process. Can I incorporate this also?

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AY$18103").AutoFilter Field:=36, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria1:=">" & Application.EoMonth(Now, -1), _
    Criteria2:="<=" & Application.EoMonth(Now, 0)
```

2. Similar to no.1, un-tick the previous months, tick the 2nd month from the current month, and to tick the following months ahead? (e.g. My data is for November 2017. I would have to un-tick the previous months, including November, then tick January 2018 and the following months ahead)
3. One of the processes that I have to do is to copy the formula from the cell to the left, then paste it to the current cell. What I do is I copy the left cell first, then use <kbd>Ctrl+Down</kbd> to go to the bottom row. Then click the right button (to go back to the original column) then <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Up</kbd> again to paste to the whole column. The code that I use is:

   ```
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
   ```

The problem is that there are certain cells in the original column that's already filled up with data (from my previous process) and I would have to at least write that code 4 times just for the cell to reach the uppermost cell. How do I code it so that it would reach the top (minus the row with the cell header) while taking note that these rows are filtered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got quite a lot of questions in a single post. But anyways, for your 1 & 2, you can try something like below:

```
Sub ject()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim myRange As Range, selMonth As String

    '*/ Below selects 1 month ahead of current month
    'to select 2 months ahead, add 2 on Month(Date) */
    selMonth = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1), _
                      "m/d/yyyy")

    With Sheet1 '/* change to your actual sheet */
        .AutoFilterMode = False '/* reset all filters */
        '/* reference last row to column A */
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set myRange = .Range("A1:AY" & lr)
        myRange.AutoFilter 36, ">=" & selMonth
    End With

End Sub
```

For number 3, you can use the same routine as above to find the *last row* (and column) and then paste data there. You can also [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba) to learn more about finding your destination ranges (cells).

Comment: Wow thank you! Worked like a charm. Can you give a simple explanation on how the code works? Most of it are new to me.

Also, if you have the time, how can I use the code above to find the last row?

Comment: `lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` This line of code actually gets the last row (lr). Now, which part of it is not clear? Already provided comments to guide you on how to use it :)

Comment: Hello sir. I've made a more manual approach in getting to the bottom row.
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Will continue on my next comment

Comment: My next step involves getting back up to the uppermost row (minus the header, which is Cell AV1)  How do I make use of the code to make sure that every row is covered, when there are lots of cells with data/and are blank on the way up? (e.g. row 555 is blank, row 450 has data, row 240 is blank, etc) When I run it, nothing happens (and I'm most definitely sure that I'm doing something wrong). Tried analyzing for hours on why this is happening, but i just can't get it :/

Comment: @Vakovich You can find a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078473/last-used-cell-in-sheet) here. You can try either and post another question when you stumble on some issue.